# How to get the element from the text using Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium

We all know finding the text present in the element is done by using `.text` .

Now how can I find the element if I have the text present.

Ex :

```
<a class="user" href="/profile/Philip-Nunn-2" action_mousedown="UserLinkClickthrough" id="__w2_hN4ZuPR_link" target="_blank">Philip Nunn</a>
```

Here I have `Philip Nunn` with me, so how can I get the element tag from this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an `xpath` for this.

```
'//a[contains(., "{}")]'.format(text)
```

This locates any anchor tag containing `text`

Comment: How did you get this, as I could not find any such thing in w3school, can you please forward me the link.